# React - state doesn't update in class component even though the message printed on the screen changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, react-class-based-component

I have an **App** component which holds an input. Every time I type in the input, the value of the input updates and a **Message** component prints a different message, depending on how long the input is. At the same time, a third component called **Character** print to the screen every letter of the string, individually. The desired behavior is that when I click on one of the letters, it gets removed from the string, the new string is displayed on the screen and the input also gets updated with the new string.

I used some console.logs to debug and everything seems to be happening as expected, until the last step when I am trying to update the state, but for some reason, it doesn't get updated.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { text: "" };
  }

  render() {
    const handleUpdateText = event => {
      this.setState({
        text: event.target.value
      });
    };

    const inputLength = this.state.text.length;
    const toArray = this.state.text.split("");

    const handleDeleteLetter = index => {
      toArray.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(toArray);
      const updatedArray = toArray.join("");
      console.log(updatedArray);
      this.setState({ text: updatedArray });
      console.log(this.state.text);
    };

    return (
      <>
        <input type="text" onChange={handleUpdateText} />
        <Message inputLength={inputLength} />

        {toArray.map((letter, index) => (
          <Character
            key={index}
            theLetter={letter}
            deleteLetter={() => handleDeleteLetter(index)}
          />
        ))}
      </>
    );
  }
}

class Message extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { inputLength } = this.props;

    let codeToPrint = "The text is long enough!";

    if (inputLength <= 5) {
      codeToPrint = "The text is not long enough!";
    }
    return <p>{codeToPrint}</p>;
  }
}

class Character extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { theLetter, deleteLetter } = this.props;
    return (
      <div
        style={{
          display: "inline-block",
          padding: "16px",
          textAlign: "center",
          margin: "16px",
          backgroundColor: "tomato"
        }}
        onClick={deleteLetter}
      >
        {theLetter}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The complete code is here:

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-the-complete-guide-assignment-2-list-conditionals-e6ty6?file=/src/App.js:51-1007

I don't really understand what am I doing wrong and I have a feeling is somehow related to a life cycle method. Any answer could help. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to the provided answer, do not log your state where you update it since setting the state is async. You can log the state in the `render` method. Also, define your methods as a `class` method instead of defining them in the `render` method. One more thing, try to avoid using an index as your key :)

Comment: This actually answers the question why is the state not the current one but the previous, when I log it. I'm not sure what you mean by "Also, define your methods as a class method instead of defining them in the render method." And yes, I know using the index as key is a bad idea, I just used it here for the sake of example. The input is much appreciated.

Comment: The answer owner updated their answer after my comment. There is an example of how can you do it. Do not define your functions in the `render` method, move them to the class field, for arrow functions drop the `const`, for regular functions drop the `function` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

State is getting updated, you just need to pass `value` prop to the input so that input's value can be in sync with your state

```
<input type="text" value={this.state.text} onChange={handleUpdateText} />
```

And you're not seeing updated state just after setting it because `setState` is asynchronous. That's why the `console` statement just after the `setState` statement shows the previous value.

Also you should move functions out of your render method, because everytime your component re-renders, new functions would be created. You can declare them as class properties and pass their reference

```
   handleUpdateText = event => {
      this.setState({
        text: event.target.value
      });
    };

render() {
.......
 return (
      <>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.handleUpdateText} />
```

Comment: I didn't even notice I didn't set a value for the input. How come it was getting updated anyway, since the value wasn't set, therefore it wasn't connected with the state (if I remove the value property and I type inside the input, it displays exactly what I typed).  Thank you

Comment: It displays what is your state actually not the value of your input. If you don't set a `value`,  your input is not going to be a controlled one. When you set a `value` there and tie it to your state, this makes them sync and your input a controlled one. You can test this. Without `value` write a long word in input, then delete most of it (letters) via your component and go to input and continue to writing. Your display will reflect what input holds immediately.

Comment: Oh, you already tested it :) The input has its value here, it is not the state. With this method, you are tying the state with the value. So, even if you don't set a value there the input will have it. You can see the [controlled](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) and [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) components part in the docs.